# MongoDb - Aggregate: How to get Grand Totals with Individual, Ungrouped Records?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have documents like:

```
{ type: "hourly", amount: 100 },
{ type: "flat", amount: 350 },
{ type: "hourly", amount: 200 },
{ type: "payment", amount: 100 },
{ type: "payment", amount: 200 }
```

Somewhere in the pipeline, I want to accumulate totals for each "type."  **Along with all the individual records**, I want to know that we have grand totals as follows:

```
hourly:  $300
flat:    $350
payment: $300
```

I have looked at **$add** and **$sum**, and these seem to be useful for adding fields for a given record and not for accumulating grand totals.

My aggregation, so far, filters all the records I want and uses no grouping.  I don't want to group the records.  I need the individual records, along with the grand totals.

I believe the **$push** command might be relevant if I have to **$group** - possibly for **$push**-ing the individual record into an array to get it back out with all the rest of the records.   See the answer here:  [Using Mongo aggregation to calculate sum of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106193/using-mongo-aggregation-to-calculate-sum-of-values)

In my case, I have an aggregate, without gathering any totals, which is shown below.  For each returned document, there is a "type" field (e.g., "hourly", "flat," "payment").

```
myAggregate = [
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    {
        $match: query
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contacts", // collection name in db
            localField: "billerId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "biller"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$biller"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "matters", // collection name in db
            localField: "matterId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matter"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matter"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contacts", // collection name in db
            localField: "matter.clientId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "client"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$client"
    },
];
```

What would "myAggregate" look like in order to accumulate grand totals and return all the individual (ungrouped) records?

After-thought:  If it is just as efficient for me to "manually" traverse the records to get the grand totals, I can do that. I am assuming it must be more efficient for MongoDb to do it since they bothered to make these kinds of features.

Edit 1:

Here is how "myAggregate" is appended to based on Veeram's suggestion:

```
// Do we need to get only records which match the matter's contactId?
if (query2 != "") {
    myAggregate.push( { $match: query2 } );
}

// Get grand totals.
myAggregate.push({ "$group": { "_id": "$transactionType",
                "documents": { "$push": "$$ROOT" },
                "grandtotal": {"$sum":"$amount"}
           }
});
```

Comment: You can add `{"$group": {    
     "_id": "$type",
     "documents": { "$push": "$$ROOT" },
     "grandtotal":{$sum:"$amount"}
  }
}` as last stage. More [info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)

Comment: @Veeram, It looks like now is the time for me to learn how to properly build an expression.  I am reading the section on [Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions), but I am not quite grasping how it is all put together.  In fact, the section I referenced on expressions doesn't contain any examples at all.  You used a fair number of expressions above, and I need a good reference in order to understand each.  For example, you did not include quotes around $sum.  Is there a good reference on building expresssions like these?

Comment: I just missed them. It matters when you reference  document fields and use embedded property names. Always use quotes anyways. Read [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and has some examples with different accumulators.$$ROOT is a system variable which provides  access to the current document.

Comment: @Veeram.  Thanks.  I just got a chance to try it to see what comes out.  I see 1 array [] with 1 element.  The 1st element has id: "hourly," documents: <all the hourly items>, and grandtotal: 1235.  The results did not include an element for type=="flat" or any other type.  Even with additional elements for each type, my results will still be grouped.  I was looking to get all the results in natural order or whatever sort order without grouping I require.   If it is just as efficient for me to forego grouping and traverse all the elements to sum their amounts, I can do that.  Just let me know.

Comment: Np. Not entirely sure why only one type shows up. I need to look at complete aggregation query with the data that you use to run the code. Regarding grouping concern : So mongodb passes data from one stage to another. `$group` stage just like sql group will require you to select all data you need for next stage. If you are looking to flatten the data so each hourly document contains the same grand total you can `{$unwind:"$document"}` and you can add `$sort` stage at the end to add order to the output documents.Regarding efficiency: You can try both and compare metrics.

Comment: @Veeram  This is an extension of the same aggregate you've helped me add a couple of other pieces to.  For purposes of testing with a simple query, my query is only { firmId: 5a5167496b6e872dfcf5e43f }.  All documents in the collection satisfy this condition.  I have 5 total documents.  4 are "hourly."  1 is "flat."  If you recall, you helped me formulate query2 to add to the pipeline if needed.  So, query2 and your group is now pushed to "myAggregate" as shown in my Edit 1, above.

Comment: @Veeram  Sorry, my fault.  I was console.logging only the 1st element.  They are all there.  I also just learned that setting the group's id to null applies the totaling to all records without grouping them.  Cool!  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

With Veeram's help, I obtained the totals by also adding a `project` stage prior to the `group` stage he suggested.  I also set the `group`'s _id to **null** (per the [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)) in order to avoid segregating all my documents into groups.

```
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        firmId: 1,

        ... plus, a bunch more fields.

        // Project some fields to allow totaling by transactionType.
        hourlyAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "hourly"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } },
        flatAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "flat"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } },
        paymentAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "payment"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } },
        expenseAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "expense"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } },
        creditAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "credit"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } },
        debitAmount: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$transactionType", "debit"] }, then: "$amount", else: 0 } }

    }
```

Then, per Veeram, I grouped as follows:

```
myAggregate.push({
    "$group": {
        "_id": null, //"$transactionType",
        "documents": { "$push": "$$ROOT" },
        "hourlyTotal": {"$sum": "$hourlyAmount"},
        "flatTotal" :  {"$sum": "$flatAmount"},
        "paymentTotal" :  {"$sum": "$paymentAmount"},
        "expenseTotal" :  {"$sum": "$expenseAmount"},
        "creditTotal" :  {"$sum": "$creditAmount"},
        "debitTotal" :  {"$sum": "$debitAmount"},
    }
});
```

It works beautifully, and everything is returned as an array with a single element.  Notice that "documents" is a property of the array element, so they can be referenced by `<arrayElements>[0]`.documents.  All of my individual totals are there (e.g., `arrayElements>[0].hourlyTotal`).